# SQL Query Exclude Records

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to query a database of guests that bought certain items. I want to see what customers bought item 'A' but not item 'B'.

I tried:

```
SELECT customerName 
FROM Customers 
WHERE NOT item = 'A' AND item = 'B';
```

But I return customers that bought both items. I would like to exclude these customers from that query.

I am using SQLite

Comment: more detail, please.

Comment: Please add the tables and their columns.

Comment: The answer depends on the database engine, which you did not specify.

Comment: See below, the top voted answer works. The addition information is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.  I like to use `group by` and `having`, because it is very flexible for many conditions:

```
SELECT customerName
FROM Customers
GROUP BY customerName
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN item = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN item = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: this is useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the MINUS operator which returns all rows in the first SELECT statement that are not returned by the second SELECT statement. Such as:

```
(SELECT customerName FROM Customers WHERE item='A')
MINUS
(SELECT customerName FROM Customers WHERE item='B');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `EXISTS` with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select c.*
from Customers c
where exists (select 1 
              from Customers c1 
              where c1.customerName = c.customerName and c1.item = 'A'
             ) and not exists 
             (select 1 
              from Customers c2 
              where c2.customerName = c.customerName and c2.item = 'B'
             );
```